# Finding first transaction after death of date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could anyone please help to enhance the query below,

```
select 
columns
from 
(
select t.*,
sum (case when TRAN_DATE >= '20170701' then 1 end)
over (partition by acct_no order by TRAN_DATE, TRAN_TIME ) as sm_i
from (
Select 
Columns
FROM 
#BASEtable DTRAN
INNER JOIN sometable 
where condition) t) t
where sm_i = 1 
order by acc_no
```

here is the data example, (attached)

```
Company Acct_no Tran_Date   Death_of_date
1   123 20170725    20170702
1   123 20170825    20170702
1   123 20170925    20170702
2   456 20191025    20200101
2   456 20191125    20200101
2   456 20191225    20200101
```

Result expected: Row no 1 , as that is the first transaction for that account after the death_of_date

I am sorting the data based on 20170701, that is it will pick the first transaction happened after this date should be picked up which is working with the above query.

Now, i want to set the value of '20170701' with the dynamic value , i.e. need the first transaction of every account after its death of date..

I replaced the partition code the below code,

```
sum(case when tran_Date > = (select death_of_date from #basetable a where a.acct_no = t.acct_no ) then 1 end)
over partition by acct_no order by tran_Date , tran_Time) as sm_i
```

but getting error saying, subquery retuned more than one result which is not application where using > , = and so on.

Please help to enhance this code in sql server. Appreciate your help in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr9VW.jpg)

Comment: How does account#456 have 3 different dates of death? What is your expected results  from the given data?

Comment: sorry for the mistake, that should be same..

Comment: Ok, so given the 3 `tran_date` are also the same, again, what is the expected result of your query

Comment: I update the screenshot, expected result should be the first transaction i need for every account after death_of_date (if any)

Comment: Given the data shown in the text of the question, please include _in the question itself_ the exact result you expect. The screenshot tells us nothing

Comment: updated, please suggest

Comment: Your query references two tables, but your sample data has only one.  Confusing.

Comment: please ignore the sometable, as its just to show that there are more table for getting the result...but the result which is partitioned in base on basetable.....first it will give the order based on the date and will sort only 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming two things:

1. You have data with the four columns you have specified.
2. For each account, you want the first row meeting your date condition.

Then you can use window functions and filtering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Company, Acct_no order by Tran_Date) as seqnum
      from t
      where tran_date > death_of_date
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: And seeing as I was as far as setting up a fiddle, and had written almost the same query, may as well include the link here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d79f69e7353d403419a5c68cea255d4e

Comment: i added this code , and working perfectly ...thanks so much :)